# Chrome not giving expected output of bootstrap code

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I am using bootstrap. I have added all the necessary references to the bootstrap library but it still will not work in google chrome. Here's a screenshot of the out put I'm getting:

[image]

I am using a jumbotron on the "This is a Jumbotron" text but it is not working. My HTML code is as follows:

```html
     <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
          <head>
            <!-- Required meta tags -->
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        
            <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        
            <title>Hello, world!</title>
          </head>
          <body>
            <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        
            <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
            <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
            <div class="Jumbotron">
        This is a Jumbotron.
            </div>
          </body>
        </html>
```

As you can see the references are included in this code but it still won't work in chrome. Please Note that I have copied this code from bootstrap.com starter template. So is there, something wrong with my browser? Please answer this question if you know the answer. Thanks in advance. There is no CSS for this code. And also I use Visual Studio Code as my code editor.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer: It wasn't about the code editor but I had installed an extension in Chrome that wouldn't let me access the script links (via script websites). Once I removed the extension (or you could try disabling it) bootstrap started to work again. This answer is to anyone out there facing the same problems as I have.